# How to expand an iframe to the document height without javascript?

Tags: html, css, iframe, frame

In brief, I want to achieve through iframes what [**this website**](http://alafasy.co.nr) achieves through frames. How is this possible with CSS and no JavaScript?

Answer (score 4):

Let's assume you have the following HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<div>
 <iframe src="http://www.example.com"></iframe>
</div>
<div>
 <iframe src="http://www.example.org"></iframe>
</div>
```

Now if you want to have (like on your example page) the first iframe to have a specific height and the second to fill the rest of the document, you could use the table values for the `display` property in css:

```
html {
height: 100%;
}

body {
display: table;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
margin: 0;
}

div {
display: table-row;
}

div:first-child {
height: 100px;
}

div:last-child {
height: 100%;
}

iframe {
display: table-cell;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
border: none;
}
```

Comment: Does this method work well with older browsers (i.e. IE6, 7 & 8)?  How "future proof" is this?